# ASP.net MVC 4, How to keep routing to default document after project publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-routing, default-document

I created a new MVC 4 project from the internet application template in VS 2012 express, [for details click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511303/deploying-mvc-4-application-to-localhost-gives-http-error-404#comment18519554_13511303)

When I wanted to publish it, I got: **HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden**

I searched for a solution, and found that it looks like a routing issue, other posts in stackoverflow give answers through modifying MVC 3 global.asax instructions.

when I tried to apply the same solution to the MVC 4 global.asax I found syntaxes too different from those of MVC 3, **i.e. RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)**

```
namespace MyMVC4
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My doubt was wrong, [This is why it happens](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739664%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), and the solution is provided by Dommer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659544/cant-run-asp-net-mvc-2-web-app-on-iis-7-5), The procedure is the same for Visual Studio 2012.